# DNS A records not updating

Tags: dns, a-records, registrar

I've logged into my registrar's account (OVH) and edited the DNS A records a couple of days ago.

I can see these changes on my registrar UI (and text file) for the DNS zones, but none of these changes are reflected when I query the information elsewhere.

Doing:

```sh
nslookup -type=A davybraun.com
```

Returns:

```sh
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   davybraun.com
Address: 192.30.252.153
Name:   davybraun.com
Address: 192.30.252.154
```

Which are old, deprecated Github pages IPs.

After the change, I would have expected to see new Github Pages IPs instead.

For the record, I don't remember having moved management of this domain name elswhere in almost 20 years. My known registrar for it appears to be authoritative, based on:

```sh
nslookup -type=NS davybraun.com
```

... returning:

```sh
Non-authoritative answer:
davybraun.com   nameserver = dns.ovh.net.
davybraun.com   nameserver = ns.ovh.net.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by rewriting the text field directly instead of relying on the user-friendly UI. Could be linked.